# Avoiding getters and setters: what is wrong with my design?

Tags: design, object-oriented

I have a class that wraps a map UI element: `Map`.

The map can have overlays that appear on top of it, in both side panels and modal windows. When these UI elements appear, I want to temporarily disable map interaction and prevent multiple overlays appearing on top of each other.

Therefore, I inject an interface, `IMap`, of `Map` into `Modal` and `SidePanel` classes, like this:

```js
class Map {
    private _isDisplayingOverlay : boolean = false; 
    public get isDisplayingOverlay() {
        return this._isDisplayingOverlay;
    }
    
    public set isDisplayingOverlay(newValue:boolean) {
        this._isDisplayingOverlay = newValue;
    }
    //Other methods here ...
}


class ExampleModalWindow {
    
    constructor(IMap) {}

    public display() {
        if (this.IMap.isDisplayingOverlay) {
            return; // exit early to prevent overlapping overlays.
        }
        this.IMap.isDisplayingOverlay = true;
        //UI logic here
    }
    
    public hide() {
        this.IMap.isDisplayingOverlay = false;
        //UI logic here
    }
    

    
}
```

I've read that getters and setters are evil and break OOP, so I assume that there is something wrong with my design. What am I doing wrong? How can I avoid using getters and setters in this example?

Edit: Added images to clarify the layout.
This image shows the different components and their relationships on the UI.
The blue rectangle is the size of the map when the sidepanel is hidden. The red rectangles are drawn around overlays (which are both sidepanels and modal windows). The map is not displayed within a modal itself, but has modals drawn on top of it.

[image: Image showing different components and their relationships on the UI]

This second image shows the approximate size of modals, if they were allowed to be shown at the same time as the sidepanel.
[image: Second image showing approximate size of modals]

Comment: Hi @DocBrown, I've added a couple of images to clarify. I cannot show screenshots of the application itself as it doesn't belong to me, but the UI is very similar to Google Maps. Hopefully the images above clarify the question.

Comment: "getters and setters are evil" sounds a bit too dogmatic; the problem they indicate is that you're grabbing data from other components on other to do something yourself (procedural programming), instead of telling those components (via method calls) what you want them to do in a higher level way (OOP). This means that the relevant code that should be extracted out of the `ExampleModalWindow` into some other component (Map, or a new one) is precisely the detail-manipulating code that you omitted. That said, some objects are really just data structures, so sometimes getters & setters are OK.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović "That said, some objects are really just data structures, so sometimes getters & setters are OK." This might be technically true, but is misleading, because data structures are the norm today. We are very far from data structures "sometimes" are ok, and are more in the "always" ok state. Also sometimes == *almost never* in applications, *maybe some*  in libraries. Being "dogmatic" about it is _much_ _much_ closer to where it should be.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam "data structures are the norm today" - the context was someone wanting to write good OOP code; "sometimes" wasn't meant as a statement about the frequency plain data structures in most code today. "Sometimes == almost never in applications" - I disagree, there's plenty of opportunity to use behaviorless data structures at the boundaries of applications, or you can mix paradigms if it fits the problem better. The way to go is not to be dogmatic, it's to develop a deep understanding of design, of the pros and cons of certain design choices.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović "The way to go is not to be dogmatic". Ok. So when I say object-orientation allows me to include the UI code in the business object and people lose their minds about it for the 100th time, I can use this "don't be dogmatic" argument, right? :)

Comment: @RobertBräutigam You missed the second half of that sentence: "develop a deep understanding of ... the pros and cons". So, absolutely, if the best argument anyone has against your design is "it doesn't follow this dogma", then you can argue back; but if they say "that mixes responsibilities, which makes these scenarios harder...", they're applying the principles reasonably. The same applies to getters and setters: they might be a "code smell" to check if the design is appropriate, but you might look at the design and realise that a plain data structure is actually appropriate.

Comment: @IMSoP I believe I did "develop a deep understanding of" the pros and cons, and in my last 5 years of software development I never even once encountered a scenario where I thought the best solution would be a data structure. The furthest I got in _rare_ scenarios is to write a couple of getters in some otherwise non-data-structure objects. I've worked on banking software, trading software, web-based apps, android apps, microservices, iot-related software, communication libraries, etc. There may come a time, but hasn't happened yet.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam I wasn't attacking your understanding, just pointing out where your straw man argument fell down, in a hypothetical conversation between two developers. Maybe in an ideal world even a basic data type like `Address` would encapsulate behaviour, but creating a plain data object with getters and setters will be better than falling back on a built-in type like `string` or `list<string>`. Discussing _why_ the rule is there might help someone build a _better_ Address type; enforcing it blindly might lead them to not create one at all.

Comment: _"I've read that getters and setters are evil and break OOP"_ I've read that we should all fear the sky falling on our heads one day, but that doesn't make it true. If you're blindly going to assume that what you read is true, then you're going to have to ask whoever wrote it how your code should be fixed. Asking others who are not aware of what you read or who wrote it and what their intention was, is simply not feasible.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam: Once again, you're injecting your personal agenda here. _Regardless_ of precisely how frequently data structures are used (which you've railed against many, many times in this community), their usage in turn warrants the existence of getters and setters. Any discussion on the frequency of data objects being used is simply not relevant. I am frankly tired of having to read your entire take on the state the field of software development, how it uses OOP, and how your career has been progressing; every time someone talks about anything remotely resembling a data structure.

Comment: @Flater "I've read that we should all fear the sky falling on our heads one day" is a poor analogy, because it relates to an objective fact, whereas the idea that a particular practice should be avoided is only ever going to be an opinion. It's reasonable to ask for the reasoning behind that opinion, and to decide if you agree with it, but it's not really meaningful to call it "false". It's also perfectly possible to generalise from one example to many cases, so you don't need to ask someone who has that opinion to apply it to every piece of code you write, you can learn to do that yourself.

Comment: @Flater I took this question to be asking: "I've read this advice, but I didn't fully understand it; can anyone use this example to help me understand it better?". My answer is on that basis, rather than splitting hairs about who wrote what when with what words.

Comment: @IMSoP: I interpret the question somewhat differently, since OP _assumes_ (quote) that their code must be wrong. There's a difference in asking whether the article they read was correct, and asking how to fix their code based on some arbitrary advice without any elaboration as to what it precisely tried to solve.

Comment: @Flater Yes, it can be read that way, but I found it more interesting to discuss the actual issue than the nuances of wording, that's why I said "splitting hairs". It feels pedantic to demand elaboration of every point when I _do_ know why the advice exists. Again, I've written an answer based on that assumption, which I think is far more useful to everyone than this debate.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam "I can use this "don't be dogmatic" argument, right? :)" - I'm more concerned about the self-study context, as the statement itself is lacking nuance, than I'm about scenarios where two devs are having a discussion. People often find something like "getters & setters are evil" online, but are offered very little to no additional context/guidance, so they misinterpret what the point of it all is. Just the other day, we had a question along the lines of "I heard getters and setters are bad, so can I just use public fields instead?", which misses the point completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the context, there may be several solutions. I will list 2:

1. Keep the boolean flag, but have the map wrap any overlays. Like this:

```java
private _isDisplayingOverlay : boolean = false; 

public overlay(UIComponent component) : UIComponent {
   // Wrap "component" with another one that sets/resets flag
   // on display()/hide()
}
```

Then create all UI Components that are overlayed through the Map.

2. Extract the positioning info (the flag whether something is overlayed) into it's own thing. For example a `Screen`, or `Page`, etc. Have this object supplied to the `display()` and `hide()` methods. Something like this:

```java
// In Map
public display(screen: Screen) {
   if (!screen.isThereAnOverlay()) {
      ...
   }
}
```

Again, it all depends on your context, there are probably other solutions too.

Comment: Thank you @robert. In my case, option 1 is more practical.

Comment: I think your solution #2 has a good start (moving the responsibility for the overlay visibility away from the `Map` into something like a `Screen`), but then the proposed solution is introducing a unnecessary dependency from `Map` to `Screen`. Why not simply give `display` a boolean parameter and let the caller pass `screen.isThereAnOverlay()` into it?

Comment: The second option here is still basically using a getter, with the problems that brings: why should other components know this specific thing about the Screen's state? That should be _internal_ knowledge, and the component should call `screen.canDisplay(this)`, or even `screen.tryDisplay(this)`, leaving the logic of what components can co-exist encapsulated in the Screen class.

Comment: @IMSoP Yes, the second solution is not my favorite, it's just an illustration of what's possible. Since components are displayed on screens there is an argument to be made that they should know about the screen. They will probably have to know all sorts of things about it to display correctly. That's all an assumption, I didn't even know it's a web-based app at that time. And also, you don't necessarily need to pass `this`, as the `Screen` received could be a specific instance for this very component.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam The problem is not with the component knowing about the Screen itself, it's with it knowing, and having responsibility for, the _specific states_ that Screen can be in. The responsibility for "only showing one overlay at a time" needs to be _entirely_ in the Screen class. See my answer for one way this can work (although I kept with Map as the owner rather than introducing a new Screen class, for simplicity).

Answer (score 2):

I'd say you're thinking about this all wrong. The map doesn't need to be aware that there's an overlay preventing it from being interacted with. The modality of the overlay is a characteristic of your UI as a whole, not of the map component.

One way to keep the map component agnostic of the overlay would be to display your overlay on top of another transparent full-screen overlay that intercepts any interactions with the map.

As for getters and setters being evil, I don't know where you heard that. Getters and setters are the bread and butter of encapsulation.

Comment: This ties in with @gnasher729 's points about strange logic. In this case, the getters and setters were a symptom of something being wrong. But it does seem to be a controversial subject. Searching google for "getters and setters are evil" returns articles like this: https://www.infoworld.com/article/2073723/why-getter-and-setter-methods-are-evil.html

Comment: @Eoin That article's argument seems to be a lot more subtle than its title suggests. It's not that getters and setters are evil; getters and setters are the correct way to expose properties. It's that having a lot of properties is evil, or at least a code smell, since OOP is really about modeling behavior, not just passing around bags of properties.

Comment: The argument goes something like this: Good encapsulation hides state, and makes it a side-effect of behaviour. Getters and setters expose state, and make behaviour a side-effect of modifying it.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede My takeaway from the article was that the ideal program would have absolutely 0 getters and setters, with the caveat that in some cases they are unavoidable. In my example above, it turns out they were indeed avoidable and a code smell.

Answer (score 2):

The idea that getters and setters are "evil" or at least a "code smell" is based on the principle that an object should hide its *state* as an implementation detail of its *behaviour*.

Let's look at some problems with your current code, and how thinking about behaviour rather than state would help us resolve them:

- If we wanted to change the logic to allow, say, a sidebar on each side, every component that currently reads or writes the `isDisplayingOverlay` property would need updating.
- Each time we add a new type of overlay, we have to remember to include the `isDisplayingOverlay` logic, because there's nothing in the design to stop us missing it out.

We can solve the first point by replacing the direct get and set with a "lock" and "unlock" method. If we pass the component we're trying to display, we can use that to make more complex decisions in future:

```
class Map {
    private _isDisplayingOverlay : boolean = false; 

    public bool tryToClaimOverlayLock(IOverlay claimant) {
        if this._isDisplayingOverlay {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            this._isDisplayingOverlay = true;
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    public void releaseOverlayLock(IOverlay claimant) {
        this._isDisplayingOverlay = false;
    }
}


class ExampleModalWindow implements IOverlay {  
    constructor(IMap) {}

    public display() {
        if (! this.IMap.tryToClaimOverlayLock(this)) {
            return; // exit early to prevent overlapping overlays.
        }
        //UI logic here
    }
    
    public hide() {
        this.IMap.releaseOverlayLock(this);
        //UI logic here
    } 
}
```

This is better - we now only have one class that needs to manage the detailed state, and can change the implementation without changing everywhere that calls it.

But our second problem remains: the design lets us forget to claim the lock, or worse, forget to release it, because "claiming a lock" is still just a way of *managing state*, and is divorced from the *behaviour* of displaying the overlay.

The underlying problem is that we've given the `display` method too many responsibilities:

- Deciding *whether* to display something
- Knowing *where* to display it
- Knowing *how* to display it

What we really want is for the decision of *whether* to display the component to be the responsibility of the `Map` class, but at the moment it's spread across both classes. The same might be true for *where* to display it (again, imagine having both left and right sidebars).

So the behaviour we want to model is:

- The `Map` decides whether to display the component
- The `Map` decides where to display it
- The `Map` tells the component where to display itself
- The component decides how to display itself in that position

The result looks something like this:

```
class Map implements IRenderingTarget {
    private _isDisplayingOverlay : boolean = false; 

    public bool displayOverlay(IOverlay overlay) {
        if this._isDisplayingOverlay {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            this._isDisplayingOverlay = true;
            overlay.renderAt(this);
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    public void hideOverlay(IOverlay overlay) {
        overlay.removeFrom(this);
        this._isDisplayingOverlay = false;
    }
}


class ExampleModalWindow implements IOverlay {  
    public renderAt(IRenderingTarget target) {
        //UI logic here
    }
    
    public removeFrom(IRenderingTarget target) {
        //UI logic here
    } 
}
```

Where previously we would have written this:

```
myModal = new ExampleModalWindow(myMap); 
myModal.display();
```

We would now write this:

```
myModal = new ExampleModalWindow(); 
myMap.displayOverlay(myModal);
```

We now have code that:

- Is shorter and less repetitive (but may seem more complex at first glance)
- Has natural places to change each part of the behaviour
- Doesn't need us to remember to re-implement the same checks in multiple places, because we've modelled the *purpose* of those checks in one place
- De-couples the components into parts that can individually be tested, linked by purpose-specific interfaces.

Note: As others have pointed out, it may be that the Map should be a separate component, with responsibility for displaying the actual map data, panning and zooming, etc. In that case, the logic here would belong in a Screen or Layout class, and the map would communicate with it in the same way as the overlays.

Comment: I'd be tempted to change `bool _isDisplayingOverlay` to `IOverlay _overlayTarget`, so that `hideOverlay` can't do the wrong thing

Comment: @Caleth Yes, that's actually a good example of why this re-factoring was worthwhile: to do that in the original code, we'd need to find everywhere that was managing the boolean flag, and update to the new behaviour, making sure we didn't miss anywhere or make a mistake. Now that we've encapsulated the state properly, that change can be made in the Map class without touching any of the other classes at all, and we can easily test that it works as expected (e.g. with a unit test).

Answer (score -1):

Some people say: Getters and setters are evil. The most common reason why they say that is because they heard someone state this with a lot of conviction. But as we all learnt, stating something with a lot of conviction doesn’t mean you’re right.

There’s a real argument in Java, where instead of using a getter and setter you might as well have used a public member variable. There’s no difference really in you example.

Your logic seems a bit weird, I assume you pass the same map to multiple overlay windows? And it shouldn’t be the modal window’s job to decide whether to be displayed or not, that should be someone else’s. Either you have a map object that shows countries and overlays, or some other object showing a map and overlays, and they should control showing/hiding the overlay windows. But your setter/getter are not the problem.

Comment: It does seem to be a dividing issue. But I do agree with the sentiment that it probably means there is a problem with the design somewhere. I agree that the logic is quite strange, I will fix this. Both of @Robert's solutions above also eliminate this strange logic!

Comment: @Eoin: you already got two good answers, so I don't write my own, but let me add, I would probably replace `Map._isDisplayingOverlay` by a boolean flag like `_isInteractionActive`. This way, a `Map` only knows that it should allow interaction or not, but not that something like an "Overlay" even exists. Then something like a `Screen` object could control the activation of overlay and coupling to the interactivity of the map.

Comment: It's best to understand an argument before disagreeing with it. The argument against getters and setters has nothing to do with the availability of public properties in a language, but to do with the idea that objects should expose _behaviour_ rather than _state_. So _in this view_,  explicitly reading or writing the `isDisplayingOverlay` property is indeed a sign that the objects are not interacting in a "good" way - which is a conclusion you came to as well, via different reasoning.

Answer (score -2):

FYI – I calmly disagree with the notion that "getters and setters are evil."  They are just procedure and function calls ... conveniently packaged.  So, as long as you are *aware* that "this is actually what's taking place whenever you use them," they surely are convenient.

Comment: As with other answers and comments, this seems to be based on a misunderstanding of what is being considered "evil" (probably too strong a word): it is not about the technical details of methods Vs properties, it's about the *design* of working with state rather than more abstract behaviour.